# How to move back the row from second table to initial table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two tables, I move need to move rows between them. First table have add button, which adds selected items from table 1 to table two. My add works fine and remove on the second table works but it does.

My tables

```
<table id="stockForOrder" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>ISNB</th>
            <th>Available Quantity</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML5/CSS3 Fundamentals</td>
            <td>R600.00</td>
            <td>00000064</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="quantityAvaliable" 
                name="quantityAvaliable" class="form-control"
                readonly value="21" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="quantity"
                name="quantity" class="form-control" value="" /></td>
            <td><input class="addLineItem" type="button" 
                value="Add"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 

 </table>

 <table id="toOrder" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>ISNB</th>
            <th>Available Quantity</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tbody>
 <table>
```

Java Script code

```
   //When the button is clicked create table 2
   $(".addLineItem").on("click", function() {

       var itemsBooks = [];
       var row = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
       itemsBooks.push(row);
       row.appendTo($("#toOrder"));
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
       $('input[type="button"]', row).removeClass('AddNew').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove');

   });
   //remove table 1 from table 2             
   $('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   });
```

Comment: Can you describe the desired behaviour and what isn't working?

Comment: The desired behavior that must take place. First table display available items to order, when by user will enter quantity of books to order. After that user can click add button to ta to table 2. On table 2 the is option to remove item if you dont want to order it. When remove is clicked that particular row will be displayed back to initial table which is table 1. Reason for remove the row select on table 1 to restrict user from ordering 1 times many times. User can only change quantity. This is my code on fsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/JayStar/afaL8mdy/

Comment: The part that i need help on is to take back [move back] the `row` to the initial `table 1` when 'remove button' is clicked on `table 2` if user don't want to order that item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $('#stockForOrder').on('click', '.addLineItem', function() {
   //     $(".addLineItem").on("click", function() {
        var itemsBooks = [];
        row = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
        itemsBooks.push(row);
        row.appendTo($("#toOrder"));
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $('input[type="button"]', row).removeClass('AddNew').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove');

    });

    //remove table 1 from table 2
    $('#toOrder').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function(){
        row = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
        row.appendTo($("#stockForOrder"));
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $('input[type="button"]', row).removeClass('RemoveRow').addClass('addLineItem').val('Add');
    });
```

Comment: this line of code `if (itemsBooks.indexOf(row.td[0])` bring an error of `Unexpected identifier`. I trid to put the if inside curly brace but no luck.

Comment: ignore the line, shouldn't impact the move line. updated my code.

Comment: @ Evelyn Ma Okay thanks a lot, Now its working after removing the line that containers the if statement.